# Adobe PDF Preview Handler delay

Tags: delphi, pdf, delphi-xe

I'm using **IPreviewHandler** interface in Delphi XE to view a list of Adobe PDF files.
Everything works except that when first view is closed (interface is being destroyed) there is a long delay of about 20 seconds.
All subsequent views proceed normally without such delay,
until, of course, I restart the application.

Has anybody experienced such strange behavior and what could be the reason for that?

The problem is reproducible with another developer on a different machine.
OS is Windows 7 Ultimate, Adobe Reader XI is v11.0.3.

CLSID='{DC6EFB56-9CFA-464D-8880-44885D7DC193}'.
Code snippet:

```
TqdPreviewControl = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FResult   : HRESULT;
    FFileName : string;
    FLastError: string;
    FComPreviewHandler : IPreviewHandler;
    function IsOk(Ret : HRESULT) : boolean;
    function UpdatePreviewSize :boolean;
    class function GetCLSIDForFileName(AFileName: string): string; static;
    function PreviewFile :boolean;
    procedure SetFileName(const Value: string);
  protected
    procedure Resize; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner :TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property FileName: string read FFileName write SetFileName;
    property LastError: string read FLastError;
  end;

destructor TqdPreviewControl.Destroy;
begin
  if FComPreviewHandler <> nil then
    FComPreviewHandler.Unload;   // this helps to reduce first delay to 5 sec
  FComPreviewHandler := nil;     //! only on first destroy spends here 20 sec
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TqdPreviewControl.PreviewFile :boolean;
var
  ACLSID: string;
  AGUID: TGUID;
  AInit: IInitializeWithStream;
  AFile: PWideChar;
  StreamAdapter : IStream;
  Stream : TMemoryStream;
  Size : TRect;
begin
  Result := false;
  FLastError := '';
  ACLSID := GetCLSIDForFileName(FFileName);
  if (ACLSID = '') then begin
    FLastError := 'No CLSID';
    Exit;
  end;

  AGUID := StringToGUID(ACLSID);
  FComPreviewHandler := CreateComObject(AGUID) as IPreviewHandler;
  if (FComPreviewHandler = nil) then
  begin
    FLastError := 'No Handler';
    Exit;
  end;

  AInit := FComPreviewHandler as IInitializeWithStream;
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Stream.LoadFromFile(FFileName);
  StreamAdapter := TStreamAdapter.Create(Stream, soOwned);
  FResult := AInit.Initialize(StreamAdapter as IStream, STGM_READ);
  StreamAdapter := nil;

  Size := Rect(0, 0, Width, Height);
  if not IsOk(FComPreviewHandler.SetWindow(Handle, Size)) then
    Exit;
  if not UpdatePreviewSize then
    Exit;

  if IsOk(FComPreviewHandler.DoPreview) then
    Result := true;
end;
```

Update: found a useful method - Unload, this reduces delay from 20 to 5 sec.

Update: further massaging has put Application.ProcessMessages in destructor, this allows the owning form to close without delay but the delay is transferred to the parent form which freezes for 5 sec. Still slightly better visually than having to see the closing view in an half-updated state.

Update: using Foxit preview handler confirmed that delay indeed is artifact of Adobe and
is not related to Delphi code at all

Comment: FYI the PDF file format is no longer Adobe's (since 1st July 2008)

Comment: @Sam thanks for pointing out, according to Wikipedia Adobe gives everybody a free license

Comment: You should update your question, but before read http://sscce.org/